# How to refresh a listview control after editting an item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I started playing with the wpf listview control. I've created an "add" button and an "edit" button.
The "add" button works as expected - whenever I'm adding a new item to the list it gets displayed.
My problem is with the "edit" button - what is the correct way of informing the listView control that an item was changed? (it works in the attached code, i just wanted to know if there is a better way)

This is my code:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow" Name="This"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    >
<Grid>
    <ListView   Name="Mylist"
                ItemsSource= "{Binding ElementName=This, Path=People}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                >
        <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="false">
                    <GridViewColumn 
                            Header="Name" 
                            Width="Auto" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn 
                            Header="Id" 
                            Width="Auto" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="45" Margin="190,133,197,133">
        <Button 
                    Content="Add"
                    Click="AddButton_Click"
                    />
        <Button 
                    Content="Edit"
                    Click="EditButton_Click"
                    />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication5
{
public class PersonalDetails
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Id {get; set;}
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<PersonalDetails> people = new ObservableCollection<PersonalDetails>();
    public ObservableCollection<PersonalDetails> People
    {
        get { return this.people; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        PersonalDetails p1 = new PersonalDetails();
        p1.Name = "Jeff";
        p1.Id = "111";
        people.Add(p1);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PersonalDetails p2 = new PersonalDetails();
        p2.Name = "Tom";
        p2.Id = "222";
        people.Add(p2);
    }

    private void EditButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PersonalDetails pItem = (PersonalDetails)Mylist.SelectedItem;
        if (pItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        pItem.Name = "Dan";
        Mylist.Items.Refresh();

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your PersonalDetails class should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.

Then when the `Name` property changes and you raise the `PropertyChanged` event the WPF binding infrastructure will respond by refreshing the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="listResult"  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}"></ListView>
```

Code Behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<object> itemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>();

public ObservableCollection<object> ItemsCollection
{
    get { return this.itemsCollection; }
}


private void UpdateSectionsList()
{
    List<object> tempList = ... //Put your element here

    // clear the list before and reload the object you want to display
    itemsCollection.Clear();

    if (tempList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (object item in tempList)
        {
            itemsCollection.Add(item);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListView.Items.Refresh();`

Helped me